# Append <script> tag to <head> fails in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've recently added a third-party javascript library to my website in order to manage email subscriptions:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/catID/formID.js"></script>
```

This javascript file contains a line to load another javascript file to style a popover that's displayed on the page:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://forms.aweber.com/form/styled_popovers_and_lightboxes.js";
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Oddly enough, this script loads fine in Safari, IE and Firefox, but in chrome the script fails to load:

[image]

Yet I can load the same script in a [new tab](http://forms.aweber.com/form/styled_popovers_and_lightboxes.js).  When I debug the network request, the only information I can gather is that there was no response:

[image]

Why would Chrome (only) be unable to load this script?

Comment: I find it *really* hard to believe that your code actually works in Firefox, or any browser for that matter. It might not result in an error, but I don't see how the script would really be loaded.

Comment: sorry guys, i made a lazy mistake and should have just copy/pasted.  I updated the code snippet to reflect the script call.  Chrome still fails to load my script, though all other browsers complete the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is blocked by AdBlocker in Chrome. If you disable it, it should work.

Maybe you could host this script on your server? Or you would need to notify your users that they have to disable their AdBlocker use everything on this site, but this probably won't make them happy.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for this tip.  Saved me lots of time!

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding a new `<script>` tag; you're just passing a URL to `.appendChild()`.

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.src = "http://forms.aweber.com/form/styled_popovers_and_lightboxes.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: Apologies, I updated my question with the actual code that appends the script.

Comment: @Kyle oh OK.  Well, you don't need the "type" attribute in any browser, so that'd be the first thing I'd try (though it looks OK here).

Comment: @Kyle [your script loads just fine in Chrome from this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/TMEM7/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to append `script` tag not url  of javascript into `head` element, something like this,

```
var script = document.createElement('script'); //creating script element.
script.src = "http://forms.aweber.com/form/styled_popovers_and_lightboxes.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(script);
```